# wrap elements in single quotes in Tcl list for sqlite insertion

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I'm trying to format a string for SQLite insertion, so we need to wrap a list of strings in single quotes depending on their type

so if I have a list as such

```
set list1 [list a b 1]
```

How would I easily convert that into a list where each string element is single quoted but the numbers are not like this

```
'a' 'b' 1
```

Is there some string formatting command that will accomplish this simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need this quoting. Sqlite interface in tcl is very flexible. If you describe your main task in detail, you could get more useful advice.

But I can give the direct answer for your question. Here it is.

```
set list1 [list a b 1 2 c]
set list_quoted [lmap a $list1 {
                            if {[string is integer -strict $a]} {
                              set a
                            } else {
                              subst {'$a'}
                            }
                          }]
```

Comment: As the sqlite interface for Tcl does prepared statements you really do not need the quoting. You are right with that remark.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I as using a quoted string in the eval statement (so that I can process a tcl statement inline).  In that case, it doesn't work unless I single quote the variables.  But I moved the tcl statements outside the eval command and then changed to braces in the eval statement, it does correctly process strings without single quotes.  Thanks

Comment: Example of prepared statement: `db eval {INSERT INTO tbl VALUES($a, $b)}`. Notice the `$a` and `$b`? Notice the `{`braces`}`? It _is_ that easy!

Comment: @donal  what I was doing was something like this db eval "insert into tb1 VALUES($a, [lindex $b 0])".  Trying that with braces wasn't working but assinging another variable like set c [lindex $b 0], then using a command like db eval {INSERT INTO tbl VALUES($a, $c)} works with braces.

Comment: @Jonjilla note that, if you are using double-quotes to enclose SQL text, you should use before the name of a variable ":" or "@" instead of "$". TCL will do the substitution of $-variables in double-quoted text, and SQLite  would interpret their values as part of the SQL statement, so this can lead to SQL injection. 


TCL will never substitute ":" or "@"-variables. But SQLite, correctly replaces the parameters with the values of the corresponding Tcl variables.